# How to include widget inside existing app in android?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an application.And I developed a widget for my application.Both of these are developed separately.I want to include this widget to my existing application.So that, when the user installs my application, widget also installed automatically.How can I achieve this?.Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I did this in one of my project. I don't have my business laptop in hand, so I have no way to show you detailed code. But I can tell you that, Android don't allow you to directly install a widget in your application. You must use Android standard way to install widget to your application. In other words, you need to invoke system widget list, just when like you long-tap on home screen a widget list is pop up. After user choose a widget from the list, your application will get the widget's handle (or id), then you can use the widget handle to embed widget view to your application's view.